# How to evaluate the divergence or convergence of x to the power of X infinite times

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

I depared myself with this problem

${{{{{{{x}^{x}}^{x}}^{x}}^{x}}^{x}}^{.....}}=a$

And studyins it I have made the assumption that if A is equal to a finite value  then the expression  is equivalent to 
$x^a=a$
 . studying this new function in terms of a , the function is increasing up to a=e , and after that point is decreasing .

How do I prove that there  for all numbers greater than e , there aren´t any x that solves this equation ? How to study properly the convergence or divergence of this function?

Asking again ,how do I conclude that the function is diverging for X superior to e ?

Comment: For $x$ superior to $e$, can you say that the function is increasing?

Comment: I wasn't entirely clear in my question . after the first assumption I begin to study the fuction f(a)=a^(1/a) , this function is increasing up to a= e ,And it has a maximum on that point (a,x) (e ,e^(1/e)).So ,if i prove that

Comment: so if i prove that the function x rise to x .....infinite times ,is increasiing after that point I prove taht is divergent after that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Euler showed that
$x^{x^{x^{...}}}
$
converges when
$e^{-e}
\le x 
\le e^{1/e}
$.

See this for discussion and references:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

I found this with
a Google search for
"euler exponential tower".

Comment: thanks. I cannot find the prove for the lower bound , and i am really curious